# Why does SQLite store strings as text in BLOB columns, rather than bytes?

Tags: sqlite, text, blob, substr

This behavior has me scratching my head: apparently, when you store a string into a BLOB column, when you query it it doesn't behave like bytes? And, weirder still, when you attempt to perform a BLOB substring, you have to query a length of 2 to get a single byte?

```
sqlite> create table wtf (a BLOB);
sqlite> insert into wtf (a) values (NULL);
sqlite> insert into wtf (a) values ('a');
sqlite> insert into wtf (a) values (X'61');
sqlite> select * from wtf;

a
a
sqlite> select a = X'61' from wtf;

0
1
sqlite> select HEX(a) from wtf;

61
61
sqlite> select substr(a, 0, 1) from wtf;



sqlite> select substr(a, 0, 2) from wtf;

a
a
```

Comment: `BLOB` **is** "bytes": Binary Large Object.

Comment: _"when you store a string into a BLOB column"_ - in SQLite, column types are ignored, so you aren't actually storing `BLOB` values, you're storing string values: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No limitation on SQL column data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70611809/no-limitation-on-sql-column-data-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does SQLite store strings as `TEXT` in `BLOB` columns, rather than bytes?

(I'll disregard your imprecise language: consider that *everything* stored in a computer is "bytes")

- [SQLite does not enforce column types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

  - *shock!* and *horror!* <sub>(...yes)</sub>
  - From the docs (emphasis mine):

    > In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its column [...] **Flexible typing is a feature of SQLite, not a bug**.
  - Read more here: https://www.sqlite.org/flextypegood.html
- When you `INSERT INTO table ( thisIsANumericColumn ) VALUES ( 'zzz' );` the SQLite engine is perfectly happy to store `TEXT` strings *as-is*, so doing a `SELECT thisIsANumericColumn FROM table` will result in your SQLite library (or your application code which consumes SQLite's API) needing to perform implicit type conversions if required, which can break at runtime (so you'd get-away with this in NodeJS or PHP, but not in .NET due to how ADO.NET works).
- There are at least 3 possible alternative solutions:

  1. Add `STRICT` to your `CREATE TABLE` DDL. This instructs SQLite to respect column types, just like a traditional RDBMS.

     - i.e. `CREATE TABLE tbl ( a BLOB NOT NULL ) STRICT;`
     - You must be running SQLite 3.37 (dated 2021-11-27) or later to use `STRICT` tables.
  2. *Simply don't insert incorrectly-typed values in the first place*.
  3. Use explicit `CHECK` constraints to enforce data-type restrictions *and* other data integrity checks, like value ranges, string length, etc.